# Scheduling node.js commands on Windows with .bat

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, automation

I am new to running **node.js** on Windows. After installing, I installed **pageres-cli** and **electroshot** and have been playing with capturing screenshots of websites.

I’m able to successfully use pageres via a CMD prompt. Like this:

```
d:\>pageres [ https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow ] [ www.bing.com/search?q=stack+overflow ] --filename="<%= url %>_<%= date %>_<%= time %>" --format=jpg --delay=3 --css="a[href*='stackoverflow.com'] {background-color: yellow; color: #7d0000;}"
```

This works beautifully. However, I want to capture these screenshots on a daily basis. So, I thought I could create a .bat file and schedule it. However, if I attempt to run pagers from inside a .bat file, it fails.

I must be missing an obvious step, but my Google-fu has failed me.

Is there some other method of calling this module other than a batch file that will allow me to automate this with Windows Scheduler?

Comment: Why does it "fail" inside a batch script? What are the error messages?

Comment: In a Batch file duplicate the percent-signs: `--filename="<%%= url %%>_<%%= date %%>_<%%= time %%>"`

Comment: @Aacini, that’s the solution! Thanks so much. I was right: the solution was obvious and right in front of me. It’s been so long since I did much with batch files that I totally forgot.